# Highcharts how to display custom tooltip in every column

Tags: highcharts, tooltip

Does anyone know if this can be done in Highcharts ?

display custom tooltip in every column, something like:

if {point.x} = January show something in tooltip 
if {point.x} = February show other thing in tooltip

.

.

thanks

Comment: Yes, see: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.formatter

Comment: that will show same tooltip for each column.. i need this: if mouse over january show 1, if mouse over february show 2, something like that.

Comment: @LmlDLGdo, wergeld is right with `tooltip.formatter` you can add specific text for each point on the chart.

Comment: that was the solution, thank you @wergeld